# Connection with empty Role

Tags: symfony

This is what I have in my security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/loginapi, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/apimobile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This is working fine, the apimobile is protected and restricted to the role user.

But now, I would like to allow the user authenticated but without any role to access it (cause I don't have any control on the user flow so I can't add them the Role User).

Meaning I have this in the database and I can't have anything else

```
a:0:{}
```

Already tried to use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` or `!IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` but not working.

Answer (score 0):

By default, every `FOSUser` has the `ROLE_USER` even if it doesn't show up in database.

Comment: Looks like they haven't otherwise I would have no problem connecting with uther without role. But actually I have.